# How did Agent K get back his fingerprints?

Tags: men-in-black

When James became Agent J, all of his normal world identities were erased. It was shown that they burned his fingerprints.

[image]

The protocols for Agent K should be same. Then, how exactly was he able to get back to normal world? How did he get back his fingerprints?

Comment: do we know that he (K) did get his prints back?

Comment: I think the point is he lived a normal life between 1 and 2 and no finger prints would have been noticed

Comment: Prosthetic fingerprints.  They glue on like nails.

Comment: It's possible to live a fairly normal life (at leastcompared to that of an MIB agent) without fingerprints. There are people who do so, due to amputation, trauma, disease, etc. And K got to keep all his fingers.

Comment: @MishaR Won't you wonder if yesterday you had fingerprints and suddenly you don't have it? Won't you go to the doctor?

Comment: K wasn't in the normal world, he was surrounded by aliens. Clearly this is an MIB safe house. Assuming he never got his fingerprints back, this could easily be explained (by someone with a flashy-thing) as being one of the side-effects of a multi-decade coma.

Comment: @InfinityWar In all honesty, I doubt I'd even notice they were gone.  It's not like I go around fingerprinting myself on a daily basis.  Keep in mind people didn't all have smartphones with fingerprint scanners in them at the time of this movie's release (and even if they did, one thinks they could reprogram the phone's fingerprint records easily enough.).

Comment: @InfinityWar Probably not. The standard protocol for a memory wipe seems to involve the MIB agent providing an immediate BS explanation of what happened. I would imagine the same applies to K's memory wipe.

Comment: How do we know the fingerprint removal was permanent? Could be that all MIB had to use the thing regularly to keep their fingerprints from healing completely.

Comment: @Dúthomhas Seeing as they were burned off, it's fairly safe to assume that the removal is permanent.

Comment: @MishaR No, all we know is J's _reaction_ to the procedure, which surprised him by leaving him with healthy, undamaged skin. It is an arbitrary assumption that the removal be permanent.

Comment: @Dúthomhas *which surprised him by leaving him with healthy, undamaged skin* Where are you getting this? As far as I can tell, J pulls back his hands back and screams "OW!!" after the surface under his fingertips turns red (https://youtu.be/Wmrwj6DDt-4). There may be no narrator saying "and then the surface turned hot," but I think the movie counts on the audience being at least somewhat familiar with the experience of burning your fingers.

Comment: I'm familiar enough with burns to know that, if what we're seeing is J having his prints burned off, he'd not be using his hands for days afterwards (not to mention he'd need the burns treating to ensure they don't get infected). So, while the explanation is likely that it was just a visual gag and not meant to be delved deeply into, it's not implausible that there's more happening here than simply burning. Perhaps the machine rewrites fingerprints, for instance, and these are stored and can be returned later.

Comment: @delinear I don't see a problem with him not being able to use his hands for days afterwards. I would imagine that's exactly how it went down. I mean, the scene is quick, but that probably because it's a montage. I doubt that getting everything in other to become an MIB agent and starting the job takes one day. Not least because part of it seems to involve burning off your fingertips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

K would likely live a relatively normal life - in the same way as real-life people do when they don't have fingerprints (such as military vets who have lost both hands).

The issue of K's confusion regarding having no fingerprints would likely be resolved by J, who would follow standard MIB protocol by providing a fictional explanation of events to K immediately after the memory wipe. This seems to be a reliable method of containment for memory wipes, and my guess is that it applies to K just as well.

Additionally, I would guess that the MIB probably provide some degree of anonymous help to their former members' legal bureaucracy hassles - even if only for the sake of further containment.

Comment: FWIW, one of my classmates had a nother who had no fingerprints due to a childhood incident with a hot stove and she got along fine. Lack of fingerprints is a bit of a mark too.

Comment: I have very shallow and some partial fingerprints due to childhood trauma on some of the fingers of one hand. I've managed to go decades without even noticing (it's only the advent of phones with fingerprint unlocking that even caused me to realise this).